# What exactly was Harry's plan in the hotel with Helen?

Tags: plot-explanation, true-lies

Recap of a part of *True Lies*: Harry (Arnold Schwartzenegger) and Albert (Tom Arnold) have a rouse planned to inject some excitement in Helen's (Jamie Lee Curtis) life.  When she gets to the hotel, after Harry tells her to lie down on the bed with her eyes closed, he starts putting the moves on her.

So I assume he tells her to close her eyes so she wouldn't see it was him.  Was he planning to go through with the rouse and hope she never opens her eyes and never realizes by touch that this mysterious French guy, like her husband, is coincidentally one of the few people in the world built like Mr. Universe?  And then just let her live with the guilt of this?

Or was he just going to surprise her mid-thrust with a "hey, open your eyes, it's actually me, your husband!" and assume that she wouldn't have one or two follow up questions?

Either way, it seemed like a really poorly thought out plan that could only end up in massive confusion mixed with outrage at best.

Comment: What excludes the possibility of him simply telling her that he is a super agent?

Comment: i think you mean *ruse*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My take on this is that Harry's original intent was to let his wife have some excitement safely (with him there to make sure all was OK).  In my mind, he was going to let her plant the listening device and leave, no matter how bad she was at playing the exotic dancer role.  Remember, her "French customer" only likes to watch.

So Harry's plan is simply to watch while she does something adventurous according to her admissions while she was being interrogated. **But…** She wound up being really good at it.  This aroused an aspect of Harry, the husband, that was completely unusual, and he couldn't resist getting closer to her.

Again, according to the way I like to interpret this, he would now (1) go back to his chair and let her leave, or (2) come clean as was stated above. Of course, he never got the chance to let us all know.